# AppCompat Action Bar library not displaying added fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, android-actionbar-compat

**EDIT**: If I extend `FragmentActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity` my layout shows up again (without an `ActionBar` of course).

The `ActionBar` works as intended on `4.x` devices, but on my `2.3` device all I get is the `ActionBar` and a **blank screen** below it. The `Fragment` doesn't seem to be getting added to the `Activity`.

**themes.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

**themes-v11.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="Widget.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

**Activity `onCreate()`**

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
myFragment = new WallFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, 
    myFragment, myFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I am using Gradle to include the `AppCompat ActionBar` library in my app.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Loading up the `hierarchyviewer` in the Android SDK's tools directory, it appears that the view you place fragments in is `android.R.id.content` on 4.x devices and is `R.id.action_bar_activity_content` on 2.3 devices running the AppCompat ActionBar library.

Unfortunately it seems that you might need to branch based off platform versions when adding fragments. This is suggested in http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58108 (not sure about 3.x devices yet).

Use this method to get the proper view for adding `Fragment`'s. My testing also shows that 3.x devices act similar to 2.3 devices when using the AppCompat ActionBar library.

```
public static int getContentViewCompat() {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH ?
               android.R.id.content : R.id.action_bar_activity_content;
}
```

### hierarchyviewer screenshots

- **2.3**

[image: 2.3]

- **4.x**

[image: 4.x]

Comment: Another thing to note is that `R.id.action_bar_activity_content` is not created until `setContentView()` is called in the ActionBarActivity. With ABS I was able to use `android.R.id.content` without a layout being set in the `Activity`, this is not the case in Android `2.x`.

Comment: @Androidy you shouldn't have to do that.  Make sure you are using the R file from your application, and not the one from support-v7 when using R.idaction_bar_activity_content.

Comment: That is the weirdest thing, but it fixed the issue. I wonder why the IDE lets you access it from both packages.

Comment: @AustynMahoney I incorporated getContentViewCompat to my fragment code and moved the fragment code to onCreateOptionsMenu and it started working on 2.3 and 4.0 ???  But I don't like this workaround at all.

Comment: This also fixes the issue when your content seems to appear above the ActionBar on Android 2.3 -- Thanks for noticing that!

Comment: @Shellum If you **update appcompat-v7 to revision 19.0.0.** or newer it is **no longer necessary to switch** between `android.R.id.content` and `R.id.action_bar_activity_content`. The different behavior is unified in the latest version of the library as you can read in the [comment of Chris Banes on issue 59077](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59077#c8).

Comment: It looks like that even after the appcompat-v7 revision 19.0.0 fix, 2.x devices will not add the fragments unless you set the content view (I am just using an empty frame layout). The part about no longer needing R.id.action_bar_activity_content is correct, but on 2.x devices it will silently fail to add fragments.

Comment: @rrbrambley Please report this issue on the bug tracker. The original bug has not been closed yet: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59077