# Custom layout with ActionBar in appcompat causes content to overlap with action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I have implemented a custom action bar layout with `AppCompat`:

```
public class DoneBarActivity {
  public interface OnSaveActionListener {
      public void onSave();
  }

  public static void setupActionBar(final ActionBarActivity activity, 
                                    final OnSaveActionListener listener) {

      // Inflate a "Done/Cancel" custom action bar view.
      final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
          .getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext()
          .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      final View customActionBarView = inflater.inflate(
          R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_done_cancel, null);
      customActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_done)
          .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              // "Done" (or "Save")
              if (listener != null) {
                  listener.onSave();
              }
              activity.finish();
          }
      });
      customActionBarView.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_cancel)
          .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              // "Cancel"
              activity.finish();
          }
      });

      // Show the custom action bar view and 
      // hide the normal Home icon and title.
      final ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
      actionBar.setDisplayOptions(
          ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | 
          ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | 
          ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
      actionBar.setCustomView(customActionBarView, 
                              new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                                  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                                  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                              )
                             );
  }
}
```

My activity is just a dumb `ActionBarActivity` that loads a fragment in a `FrameLayout`. Here's the fragment code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, 
                         final ViewGroup container, 
                         final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...

    DoneBarActivity.setupActionBar((ActionBarActivity) getActivity(), 
                                   new DoneBarActivity.OnSaveActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSave() {
                    saveIssueChangesAndClose();
            }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Here's the action bar layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:divider="?attr/dividerVertical"
              android:showDividers="middle"
              android:dividerPadding="12dp">

    <include layout="@layout/include_cancel_button"/>
    <include layout="@layout/include_done_button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here are the two buttons:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             style="?actionButtonStyle"
             android:id="@+id/actionbar_cancel"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
            style="?actionBarTabTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@android:string/cancel"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

and

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             style="?actionButtonStyle"
             android:id="@+id/actionbar_done"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
            style="?actionBarTabTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_done"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/save"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here's the result in Jelly Bean vs. Gingerbread (Galaxy Nexus for the first, emulator for the latter):

[image: ActionBar compat with Gingerbread overlap bug]

*Sorry for the quality, the animated PNG didn't work properly so I switched to animated GIF.*

As you can see, the content layout is going over the action bar custom layout (notice the blue overflow in JB and scrollbar position).

Using a non-custom action bar layout works properly on both JB and GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overlay is caused due the different resource id used to reference the content view in different versions of Android. Please refer to the [post of Shellom for detailed information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17998802/356895). Meanwhile, the following snippet should help you to identify the relevant portion of your code.

```
// http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58108
private static int getContentViewCompat() {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH ?
            android.R.id.content : R.id.action_bar_activity_content;
}
```

---

**Update:** The switch is no longer needed. You can update **appcompat-v7 to revision 19.0.0.** or newer and then reference `android.R.id.content` on all Android versions.