# How to prevent the Android title bar from covering the first view item?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've tried a bunch of different permutations setting padding, height, etc, and different layout attributes, but still can't figure out why the Android title bar covers the first View item (EditText).

The layout xml looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Blotter" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/order_entry"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/dummy_order"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:text="@string/dummy_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/orders"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/status"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/order_entry" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the result in the emulator looks like this:

[image: Android screen shot] It's a little hard to see, but I circled the EditText view which the title overlaps.  The rendering in the Eclipse ADT Graphical Layout view looks fine, though.

Comment: Are you using an action bar library such as ActionBarSherlock? Are you using fragments? or using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY ? Post the code on how you are using that layout. Meanwhile, here's another question that might be related to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635440/custom-layout-with-actionbar-in-appcompat-causes-content-to-overlap-with-action

Comment: @frozenkoi: this was just a basic, starter project. No ActionBar, and generally taking the default settings when creating Eclipse Android project. I'll post the code shortly (but there's pretty much nothing to see).  Somehow just the default Xml settings doesn't prevent the title from overlapping first View item.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` yet?
It's will be called in `onCreated` in your Activity like this:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: Well, I kind of liked having the title visible... Is it standard to hide the title?

Comment: Those calls above will completely hide the title.
Do your theme have FullScreen feature?
Because, I think the content layout is below the title by default

Comment: The project setup (by default) has `android:Theme.Light`.